# Lodash Filter items by property value not in an array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects I am trying to filter using lodash. The end goal is to return any objects from the array where the value of a property is not in another array.

```
let inUse = ['1','2'];
let positionData = [{ 
    fieldID: '1',
    fieldName: 'Test1'
},
{ 
    fieldID: '2',
    fieldName: 'Test2'
},
{ 
    fieldID: '3',
    fieldName: 'Test3'
}]

// Only show me position data where the fieldID is not in our inUse array
const original = _.filter(positionData, item => item.fieldID.indexOf(inUse) === -1);
```

I tried using `indexOf` but I don't think I am using it right in this situation.

**Expected Result:**

```
original = { 
 fieldID: '3',
 fieldName: 'Test3'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have your `indexOf` backwards; currently, it's looking for `inUse` inside of `item.fieldID`.

Try this:

```
const original = _.filter(positionData, item => inUse.indexOf(item.fieldID) === -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`_.differenceWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#differenceWith):

```js
const inUse = ['1','2'];
const positionData = [{"fieldID":"1","fieldName":"Test1"},{"fieldID":"2","fieldName":"Test2"},{"fieldID":"3","fieldName":"Test3"}];

const result = _.differenceWith(
  positionData, 
  inUse, 
  ({ fieldID }, id) => id === fieldID
);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```